# T-sql CTE recursion

Tags: t-sql

I just want it to return 
1
2

```
WITH 
CTE1 AS
(
    select value
    UNION ALL
    select value=value+1
    FROM CTe1
    WHERE value =2
)

select * from cte1
```

how come that doesnt work.

Comment: please go and read Books online for CTE syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will print out `1, 2`:

```
WITH 
CTE1 AS
(
    select 1 as value
    UNION ALL
    select value=value+1
    FROM CTe1
    WHERE value = 1
)

select * from cte1
```

The problem was that `value` was not defined for your first CTE clause.  I assume you wanted 1.  Then the second CTE clause self-references the first one and adds `1`.

Comment: pretty weird i tried values=1 before i have to use 1 as value?

Answer (score 1):

The CTE will print 1 and 2 as rows.  Is this what you are after?

```
WITH 
CTE1 AS
(
    select 1 as value
    UNION ALL
    select value=value+1
    FROM CTe1
    WHERE value < 2
)
select * from cte1
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a code to search a string for a character macth thank you all.

```
Begin
with recursiveCTE(matchNumber, foundAt) as (
  select 1, charindex(@toFind, @ToSearch, 0)
  union all
  select matchNumber + 1, charindex(@toFind, @ToSearch, foundAt + 1)
  from recursiveCTE where foundAt > 0
)
select
  matchNumber as "Match Number",
  (case when foundAt = 0 then null else foundAt end) as "Found At"
from recursiveCTE
where  foundAt  0 or matchNumber = 1
;

end;
```